# Only first random quote fades in

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a random quote generator app. When I try to add the fading effect in my JS (on click), it only works for the first quote.

```js
var quotes = {
    quote1: "Life isn’t about getting and having, it’s about giving and \
being - Kevin Kruse - ",
    quote2: "Whatever the mind of man can conceive and believe, it can \
achieve - Napoleon Hill - "
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // function generator
  var randQuote = function(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    //print key values randomly
    return obj[keys[Math.floor(keys.length * Math.random())]];
  };
  // function display
  $("button").click(function myQuote() {
    $("#demo").fadeIn();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = randQuote(quotes);
  });
});
```

```css
#quote {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 2%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px #161616;
}

.paragraph {
  line-break: auto;
  font-family: 'Satisfy', cursive;
  font-size: xx-large;
  margin: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.display {
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
}

.title {
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
  margin: 20px;
}

.btn-custom {
  margin: 20px;
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
  font-size: x-large;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 35%;
  left: 30%;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: -200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
      <h1 class="title"><strong>Random Quotes For You</strong></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" id="quote">
      <p id="demo" class="paragraph"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-5">
      <button onclick="myQuote()" class="btn btn-primary btn-custom">New Quote</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: fadeOut and fadeIn again

Comment: Also remove the `onclick` attribute, that's what's causing the error in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fade in the quote at the beginning, then fade it out and replace it with the new quote, then fade back in. You can change the "500" to whatever fade time suits best.

Also, you can get rid of the `onclick="myQuote()"` on the `<button>` element.

```
$("button").click(function myQuote(){
  $("#demo").fadeOut(500, function(){
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = randQuote(quotes);
  });
  $("#demo").fadeIn(500);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. What about without fadeOut ?

Comment: Well you have to fade the text in and then out, otherwise the transitions between new quotes will look pretty choppy. I don't think I quite understand what you're asking.

Comment: sorry I forget to remove the on click event in my html. It wa causing a choppy behaviour. It is working perfectly now, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You've already called the fadeIn on that element. You need to fade it out then flip the html and fade it back in. Once you understand the WHY you must do that then you should look at fadeToggle as it provides and animation complete callback so you can have a smother transition with loading your html then showing it again with the fade in.

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var flip = $("#div1");
    flip.fadeToggle('slow', function (){flip.html('weee').fadeToggle();}); 
});
```

Comment: @Dr.YounesHenni Don't be afraid to try things and see if you can solve the problem.

Comment: @Dr.YounesHenni Edited my answer with an example. tadman is right though, these are some basic understanding and it will help you learn with trial and error so do not be afraid to fail.